# style rails checkboxes with bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox

I have checkboxes in rails like this:

```
<%= f.label "Area of Expertise" %><br />
 <%= f.collection_check_boxes :expertise_ids, Expertise.all, :id, :name do |b| %>
  <form role="form form-group">
   <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <%= b.check_box %>
     <%= b.label %>
   </label>
  </form>
<% end %>
```

But the checkboxes are all displaying in a list going down and not across like its supposed to using the `checkbox-inline` class.

Comment: What's the output HTML of the code? What styles are applied to the element factually?

Comment: Also, what's the purpose of empty <%= b.label %> inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to create a new form for each label and checkbox. Do you need it? What if you change to:

```
<form role="form form-group">
 <%= f.collection_check_boxes :expertise_ids, Expertise.all, :id, :name do |b| %>
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
   <%= b.check_box %>
   <%= b.label %>
  </label>
 <% end %>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks, the form was the problem, it was creating a new form every time, thanks again